# PHP - How i can find a partial word in array?

Tags: php

I have a word:

```
 $word = "samsung";
```

I have array:

```
$myarray = Array(
[0] => "Samsung=tv"
[1] => "Apple=mobile"
[2] => "Nokia=mobile"
[3] => "LG=tv"
```

I need now something like this to find a partial match:

```
 if($word in $myarray){ echo "YES"; } // samsung found in Samsung=tv
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php
$myarray = array("Samsung=tv", "Apple=mobile", "Nokia=mobile", "LG=tv");


function findSimilarWordInArray($word, $array) {

    if (empty($array) && !is_array($array) return false;

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if (strpos( strtolower($value), strtolower($word)) !== false) {
            return true;
        } // if
    } // foreach

}

// use case

if ( findSimilarWordInArray('samsung',$myarray) ) {
    echo "I've found it!";
}
?>
```

It allows you to look for a similar word in array values.

Answer (score 3):

You want `in_array` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

```
if(in_array($word,$myarray){ echo 'yes'; }
```

Comment: Hi, in_array() reply true only if I search full string, `samsung=tv`. I need only `samsung` search inside string `samsung=tv`

Comment: but I guess that searching for `samsung` in `Samsung=tv` is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for partial matches, you can use strpos() with a foreach loop to iterate through the array.

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {

    if (strpos($value, $word) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Yes";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function to do a partial match, but you can easily create your own:

```
function in_array_partial($needle, $haystack){
    $result = false;

    $needle = strtolower($needle);
    foreach($haystack as $elem){
        if(strpos(strtolower($elem), $needle) !== false){
            $result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(in_array_partial('samsung', $myarray)){
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function my_in_array($word, $array){
 forach($array as $value){
  if(strpos($word, $value) !== false){
   return true;
  }
 }
return false;
}
```